# Pass data from one component to another and reflect in view

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

In my project i have two components

**component1.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyserviceService } from '../myservice.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-component1',
templateUrl: './component1.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./component1.component.css']
})
export class Component1Component implements OnInit {

constructor(private Service: MyserviceService) { }
 employee = [
 { id: '001', name: 'michael' },
 { id: '002', name: 'john' },
 { id: '003', name: 'james' },
 { id: '004', name: 'joe' },
 ];
 ngOnInit() {
 }

 onSelect(name) {
  alert(name);
  this.Service.setValue(name);
 }
 }
```

html

```
<div *ngFor="let emp of employee" (click)="onSelect(emp.name)">
Id: {{emp.id}} <br />
Name:  {{emp.name}}
</div>
```

Here onclick emp.name is passed to a service via onselect()

i need this value to be passed to a second component

component2.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
selector: 'app-component2',
 templateUrl: './component2.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./component2.component.css']
 })
 export class Component2Component implements OnInit {
 private selectedName: string;
 constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  }
```

html

```
<p>
selected name is: {{selectedName}}
</p>
```

service code is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyserviceService {
 private myValue;
  constructor() { }
   setValue(val) {
    this.myValue = val;

  }

  getValue() {
    return this.myValue;
 }
 }
```

i need to display name in component2 html code as variable selectedName.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use an observable to actively notify subscribers about value changes:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyserviceService {
  private myValue = new BehaviorSubject<String>(null);
  public myValue$ = this.myValue.asObservable();
}
```

```
 export class Component2Component implements OnInit {
 private selectedName: string;
   constructor(service:MyserviceService) { 
     this.service.myValue$.subscribe(val => this.selectedName = val);
   }
 }
```

Comment: i have added  
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
      private myValue = new BehaviorSubject<String>();
      public myValue$ = this.myValue.asObservable();
It shows error like ,
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.)

Comment: private myValue = new BehaviorSubject<String>();

Comment: now no errors,but  view not updated,is it because i missed something?.

Comment: Are you talking about `selected name is: {{selectedName}}` and is this part of `Component2Component`s template?

Comment: yes that part is html code of component2, as the div from component1 is clicked the clicked name should be set to "selected name is: {{selectedName}}"
im using service to set this name to component2.

Comment: Where do you provide the `MyserviceService`?

Comment: code for myserviceService is provided in the question,and it is imoprted in component1 and on click the function from the sevice is used to set the value

Comment: I mean where did you add `providers: [MyserviceService]`. You need to have this somewhere, otherwise you'd get an error message when running your code.

Comment: its added in app.module.ts

Comment: Sorry, can't imagine what would not work. At least I would expect an error.

Answer (score 0):

Angular documentation talks about using @Input bindings
[https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child][1]

In your component 1 html format id and name within square brackets and the replace div tag with name of component 2 selector tag

```
<app-component2 *ngFor="let emp of employee" (click)="onSelect(emp.name)"
  [hero]="hero"
  [master]="master">
</app-component2>
```

In your component 2 .ts file add a import and the input variables

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';


export class Component2Component {
  @Input() Id: string;
  @Input() Name: string;
}
```

In your component 2 html

```
<p>
selected name is: {{Name}}
</p>
```