# Passing Value through components in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using the Ng2Bs3ModalModule to show popup a component. Here for this I am using the following way :

I create a template on the master component as follow

```
<modal #modal>
    <modal-header [show-close]="true">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Update Job Service</h4>
    </modal-header>
    <modal-body>
        <app-job-service-edit></app-job-service-edit>
    </modal-body>
</modal>
```

Thereafter, I open this model using the following model.open() in (click) event.

```
<button type="button" class="flat btn-danger" name="table_records"  (click)="modal.open()">EDIT</button>
```

Now I need to pass a value to the  component by clicking the above button. How do I do this???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use semicolumn, and set a value to scope.

`<button type="button" class="flat btn-danger" name="table_records"(click)="modal.open();scopevalue='test'">EDIT</button>`

Comment: the modal component can access the master component' directly, no need to pass.

Comment: Please check the answer by me on the post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385142/pass-data-from-one-component-to-another-and-reflect-in-view/42386408#42386408

Answer (score 0):

You can use another function call to send a value using a semicolumn.

**`(click)="modal.open();(click)="test('hello')`**

```
<button type="button" class="flat btn-danger" name="table_records"  (click)="modal.open();(click)="test('hello')">EDIT</button>
```

Here is the component example.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  styles: [`
    .app {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 25px;
      background: #f5f5f5;
    }
  `],
  template: `
    <div class="app">
       <a (click)="test('hello')">Click me to alert</a>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {


  test(value): void {
  console.log(value)
  alert(value)
}

}
```

[**Here is a workinf DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/UTpXiX9YKbPySFq23VsD?p=preview)

Comment: @nifCody, please check my answer.